# Multiple WEP keys which can be retrieved from the Pcap file

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap

Ok, i have this Cap file that i captured with Wireshark. There are multiple WEP keys which can be retrieved from the file.

Is there a way, using Wireshark or aircrack-ng, to know exactly how many wep keys that are available in that Pcap file ?

Edit: not the Wep passwords, just the number of Wep keys available.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark has a display/filter field named `wlan.wep.key`.

So: Using `tshark` with a display filter and `wc` as follows might give you the desired result (altho i haven't tried it):

`tshark -R wlan.wep.key -r <filename> | wc -l`

Note: I don't know if there can be more than 1 WEP key in a frame. If so then the above won't give the right count.

`tshark -R wlan.wep.key -Tfields -eframe.number -r <filename>` should show just the frame numbers of all the frames with WEP keys.

`tshark -R wlan.wep.key -Tfields -eframe.number -ewlan.wep.key -r <filename>` will print out all the keys (even if more than 1 per frame).