# How to display WEP key from pcap file in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, tshark, wifi

I am following the following post to display the WEP key using Wireshark 3.0.1 on Windows

[Multiple WEP keys which can be retrieved from the Pcap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004315/multiple-wep-keys-which-can-be-retrieved-from-the-pcap-file)

However, I am not able to see the WEP key although I see WEP related parameters like IV and ICV

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v8st.jpg

How can I get the WEP key of the Wireless Access Point?

I also tried tshark on the command line with the following command

```
tshark -R wlan.wep.key -2 -Tfields -eframe.number -r file.pcap
```

But I get the following (showing last few lines of the output of the above command but all look like this)

```
19401   0
19402   0
19403   0
19404   0
19405   0
19406   0
19407   0
19408   0
19409   0
19410   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it turns out the you can use aircrack-ng to do this. Here is the command that I ran to extract the WEP key from  pcap file. The command can be run on Kali Linux or Ubuntu

```
aircrack-ng -z filename.pcap
```

Here is the output of the above command

```
    Aircrack-ng 1.1


                              [00:00:09] Tested 4138 keys (got 15273 IVs)

   KB    depth   byte(vote)
    0    1/  5   6B(21760) 0B(19968) CF(19968) B5(19712) 98(19200) E8(19200) 37(18688) 
    1    0/  2   F7(23808) 17(21760) 19(20224) 10(19968) BB(19968) 9F(19712) 68(19456) 
    2    1/  7   F7(21760) 60(20992) 1B(20480) 0E(20224) 98(20224) 61(19456) 6E(18944) 
    3    6/ 14   3F(19456) E8(19456) C3(19200) E6(19200) 1A(19200) 8C(18944) B2(18944) 
    4    3/  5   67(20224) 94(19968) BE(19456) C2(19456) 2A(19200) 8D(19200) 6F(18944) 

                         KEY FOUND! [ AA:BB:CC:DD:EE ] 
    Decrypted correctly: 100%
```